# Rmarkdown won't compile to html or pdf

Tags: r, utf-8, compiler-errors, r-markdown

I have a problem when compiling my rmarkdown to html. When I compile i receive the next message:

```
[WARNING] This document format requires a nonempty <title> element.
  Please specify either 'title' or 'pagetitle' in the metadata,
  e.g. by using --metadata pagetitle="..." on the command line.
  Falling back to '1570037.knit'

Output created: 1570037.html
Warning messages:
1: In readLines(con, warn = FALSE) :
  entrada inválida encontrada en la conexión de entrada '1570037.Rmd'
2: In xfun::read_utf8(input) :
  The file 1570037.Rmd is not encoded in UTF-8. These lines contain invalid UTF-8 characters: 2, 3, 29, 91, 92, 95, ...
3: In readLines(con, warn = FALSE) :
  entrada inválida encontrada en la conexión de entrada '1570037.knit.md'
4: In readLines(con, warn = FALSE) :
  entrada inválida encontrada en la conexión de entrada '1570037.knit.md'
```

And I cant compile the script. Does someone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

First, try to set the header like this:

```
---
title: "Your Title"
output: html_document
---
```

Then, try to render the file in your R console like this:

```
rmarkdown::render('your_file.Rmd', encoding='UTF-8')
```